# Can I install apps to different devices from one device?

Tags: applications, multiple-devices

I am wondering if there is a way to install and open apps on different devices I am signed onto from one device.

Comment: Do you mean like remotely controlling one device with another device?

Comment: Say a person has a few phones and or devices that they are signed onto and they want to download and install an app on them all by using one device to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is *Apps Syncing* across multiple devices. AFAIK, there is no native way to directly do this. You would need to have something like what this [App Sync app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yottajoy.appsyncfree&hl=en) is promoting.

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I am not associated with the app's company or developers in any way. I just did a quick search and their app was the first one to show up.</sub>

IMHO, I think apps syncing would is convenient, but may result to some crashes, since there is a chance where your devices each are using a different Android OS version, different specs, and last but not the least is app device specific compatibility (e.g. Tablet-only apps).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all devices must be linked to the same google account.
Access google play store via browser, when you find an app you want to install you will have a drop-list to choose on which device you want to install it so choose one device and hit install than second and hit install and so on.